# Node.js/Javascript introducing methods to existing object by setting __proto__

Tags: javascript, node.js

TL;DR - Can mixin-like behavior be achieved by setting the `__proto__` attribute?

I have a list of objects (fetched from some external source), which all have the same set of attributes (say, `_name`). I want to add to each one of them some common methods (say, `nameLen()` which returns the length of the `_name` attribute). Here is one way to do it:

```
// In reality this list of docs is generated by the DB driver:
var docs = [ { _name: 'some name' }, { _name: 'some other name' } ]

// Now, I want to introduce a method to each doc...
docs.forEach(function(doc) {
  doc.nameLen = function() { return this._name.length; }
});
```

Then I realized I can achieve a similar behaviorby setting the `__proto__` attribute of each doc:

```
// In reality this list of docs is generated by the DB driver:
var docs = [ { _name: 'some name' }, { _name: 'some other name' } ]

// Now, I want to introduce a method to each doc...
var myMixin = { nameLen: function() { return this._name.length; } };
docs.forEach(function(doc) { 
  doc.__proto__ = myMixin; // <-- Use myMixin as the prototype
});
```

Assuming all I want to add is methods and not state this seems like a more elegant solution:
(a) saves space; (b) I can later add method to `myMixin` and they will instantaneously be available at all docs.

On the other hand, fiddling with `__proto__` seems a bit risky, but I'm not sure about, hence my question:

Is it safe to introduce methods to pre-existing objects by changing their `__proto__` attribute?

Comment: @Paulpro - can provide a pointer as to how to "extend it with..." ? there are many ways to alter Objects in JS so I am wondering what precisely you had in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It would probably be better just to have explicit class rather than ad hoc inline proto changes.

```
var Doc = require( "./doc.js" );

//FIXME configure your driver/schema so that Doc objects
//are returned in the first place
var docs = docs.map(function(v) {
     return new Doc(v._name);
});

//Done
```

Doc.js:

```
module.exports = (function() {
    var method = Doc.prototype;

    function Doc( name ) {
        this._name = name;
    }

    method.nameLen = function() {
        return this._name.length;
    };

    return Doc;
})();
```

But yes, that would be safe even though it doesn't look too maintainable to me.

Comment: Please note that the docs are fetched from an external data source, I have no control on their creation.

Comment: @ItayMaman that doesn't change things too much :P Even though it would be better to make the DB driver return `Docs`. If you are using Mongoose, define the schema using Doc objects and so on.

Comment: Well, this was triggered by me moving away from Mongoose, so I'm actually trying to imitate the good part of Mongoose.